# Handler postDelayed not able to update UI

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-handler

Hello guys I'm trying to update the UI after a short delay and for this I'm using handler's postdelayed method. The following code initially sets my textview text to "Processing" and the code that's included in the the handler's runnable gets executed but doesn't update the UI? Please note that this is done in a Fragment

```
TextView progressText=(TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.inProgressText);
progressText.setText("Processing");

getActivity().getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        TextView progressText=(TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.inProgressText);
        progressText.setText("Request completed");              
    }
}, 3000);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: whats wrong with that code?

Comment: @pskink This code initially sets my textview text to "Processing" but  the code thats included in the the handler runnable gets executed but doesnt update the UI?

Comment: Could it be once your using `parent.findViewById(R.id.inProgressText);` and the next time your using `uiObject.findViewById(R.id.inProgressText);`?

Comment: @ Tom Hart sorry that's just a typo. Ive just updated my post

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
getActivity().getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable()
```

to:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Then

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final TextView progressText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.inProgressText);
        progressText.setText("Request completed");              
    }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Initially started with the same which didn't work and later changed my code to what you see right now.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView progressText = null;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

    progressText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.inProgressText);
    progressText.setText("Processing");
    progressText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progressText.setText("Request completed");
        }
    }, 3000);
       return rootView;
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry Rajan that didnt work and please note that this code snippet is in a Fragment

Comment: but u can convert it into fragment

Comment: Yes Ive already implemented the same in a Fragment which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way : I checked in Fragement and it is working perfectly.

```
View parent= inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragement, container, false);
TextView progressText=(TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.inProgressText);
progressText.setText("Processing");

            progressText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressText.setText("Request completed");
                }
            }, 3000);
```